# Execute Django fixtures on table creation

Tags: python, django, json, initialization, fixtures

Is there a way to execute a Django fixture just once - when the appropriate table is created? I have some initial data that should be put in the app tables, but once the tables are there, I don't want every `./manage.py syncdb` to refresh the data. According to Django docs it seems this can only be done for fixtures in SQL format and not JSON / YAML:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/

Comment: Same thing with a south migration. I think my initial_data.json gets reloaded with every south migration.

Comment: How about creating your own version of syncdb by either subclassing it or just copying and modifying it's code? The django command framework is quite good.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you point me to the right place in the docs?

Comment: Sure: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use the [post_syncdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#post-syncdb) signal, and filter/manually load the fixture via the underlying methods when specific apps or models are created.

Comment: Oh, right. I heard about signals but didn't actually get to reading about it just yet. Thanks for the suggestion.